# Why is the value of f when I print it always 0?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I wrote this little program in java, and the value of f is always 0. I dont see the logical error.I did this exact same thing in python and it works flawlessly. I dont get what im missing.

```
public class factorial{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int n = 1;
        int f = 1;
        while (true){
            n++;
            f = f * n;
            System.out.println(f);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: always?  Have you stepped through the code?  Are you sure that the code doesn't print expected values `(2, 6, 24, 120...)` before eventually printing `0` continually?

Comment: This should be running fine in the first couple of steps, however your `f` becomes very large very quickly. So large that the value cannot be held by an `int` anymore, so the value overflows. If that keeps repeating long enough, `f` eventually might become `0`. Then it will remain `0` forever because of the multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you do not always get 0. Your output looks like this:

```
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
1932053504
1278945280
2004310016
2004189184
-288522240
-898433024
109641728
-2102132736
-1195114496
-522715136
862453760
-775946240
2076180480
-1853882368
1484783616
-1375731712
-1241513984
1409286144
738197504
-2147483648
-2147483648
0
0
0
0
...
```

This is problem with int overflow in infinite loop.

I don't familiar with Python, but if you want something `int` without overflow, you can look at `BigInteger` class in Java.